# In the Transformers movies, what Air Force rank is U.S. Air Force Combat Controller Robert Epps suppose to be?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series

Tyrese Gibson plays U.S. Air Force Combat Controller Robert Epps (a member of Captain Lenox's special team) who supposedly holds the rank of Technical Sergeant (5 stripes, pay grade E6), but he's actually shown wearing the rank of a Chief Master Sergeant (8 stripes, pay grade E9).

[image]

#### Technical Sergeant (E-6)

- Air Force Technical Sergeant (TSgt) The Technical Sergeant (TSgt) is the second level of the Non-Commissioned Officer (NCO) ranks in the Air Force.
- Technical Sergeants are qualified to perform highly complex technical duties in addition to providing supervision. In addition, they're responsible for the career development of each subordinate under their supervision.
- It is the TSgt's responsibility to ensure that all enlisted personnel have the tools, training and support they need to achieve maximum performance and accomplish total mission effectiveness.
- The average Air Force wide active duty time for promotion to the rank of Technical Sergeant is 12 years.

#### Chief Master Sergeant (E-9)

- Air Force Chief Master Sergeant (CMSgt) The rank of Chief Master Sergeant is the highest Air Force enlisted rank, with the exception of the Chief Master Sergeant of the Air Force.
- The CMSAF is a distinctive rank with special basic and retired pay rates set by law. Chief Master Sergeants serve as managers and superintendents, advisors, enlisted force managers, and provide senior enlisted leadership.
- Following selection, CMSgts are assigned Chief Enlisted Manager (CEM) codes and may fill any managerial-level position and perform all duties not prohibited by law or directive.
- The average service wide active duty time for advancement to the rank of Chief Master Sergeant is more than 22 years. REF: From the [Air Force Handbook](http://airforcehandbook.org/files/2010/11/air-force-ranks.jpg?446863)

TSgt are typically in their 30's, whereas CMSgts are office pogues in their 50's. Is this just the result of poor understanding of military rank structure or a deliberate plot twist?

Comment: One day I'll learn how to do that.

Comment: What's that, Morgan?

Comment: I don't really see what you're asking. Is this just a rant about the fact that he's been promoted a bit quickly between the first and second film? Don't forget that it's been like 2 years since the events of Transformers to Transformers : The Fallen

Comment: Make a hotlink into an actual pic and condense others down to a title. It presents a much clearer and cleaner post.

Comment: Are you aware that he was a Tech Sergeant in the first film (http://www.visualhollywood.com/movies/transformers/pics/pics30-1.jpg) and the pic you've posted is from the second film?

Comment: For the record, this IS a legitimate question since it is unlikely the character would have advanced THREE MAJOR PAYGRADES in only TWO years, I don't care what his accomplishments may have been, the military (of which I was a member) has protocols and standards for rank increases. Two years does not replace ten to fifteen years.

Comment: @Richard - Yes of course. But as a former USAF TSgt myself, I understand what is involved in the promotion process. The movie producers obviously have 'guidance' to military protocols so this led me to the conclusion that there is 'more than meets the eye' going on.

Comment: @Morgan - I'm guessing that someone who's involved in the defence of the entire planet would get promoted rather quickly.

Comment: Sorry. I disagree. He may possess specialized knowledge and may need to command specialized resources, but they still wouldn't GIVE him the rank. They might GIVE him a boss, or give him control over resources without having to deal with any go betweens but RANK increases like that are almost always linked to technical accomplishments, tools and specialized training. Yes, its Hollywood, so they have no problem with increasing rank but the real military IS MUCH, MUCH SLOWER.

Comment: @Thaddeus - Rubbish. The planet is on a war footing and that always leads to faster promotions. The youngest CMS in US history was just 31 years of age, younger than the character in Transformers.

Comment: It leads to faster promotions when the upper ranks are clear. During long wars, promotions are more common and often faster but considering how isolated the events in transformers are, I don't see a lot of older CMS biting the dust to make room for younger ones to be promoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Yes, this is a continuity error (possibly in costuming) or possibly because when actors are portraying military staff in movies, their costumes are supposedly not entirely correct due to military regulation. They usually accomplish this by making minor changes in breadboards (the medals worn by military personnel).

> - Tyrese Gibson's character is listed as Master Sergeant Epps, a grade of E-7. The rank stripes on his uniform are a Chief Master Sergeant, a grade of E-9. REF: IMDB

- This is a minor mistake but one only military people are likely to recognize. Activate your "suspension of belief" baffles and you will be fine. Considering how young the character is, it is VERY unlikely he would have achieved E-9 rank at his age.
- I will concede the idea he may have been promoted to allow him access to resources without giving him a supervisor or revealing any more information about the Transformers to anyone who wouldn't need to know.

[image]

*Here is a better shot of his very advanced rank.*

Comment: Perhaps the promotion was to shoehorn him into the minimum rank necessary to have clearance to work with the Transformers? And promoting him early would mitigate needing to bring someone else into the secret.

Comment: Very unlikely to have achieved which rank, E-7 or E-9?

Comment: @Xantec Rank does not denote special access or clearance level. He could have received an 'accelerated promotion' to the next higher rank (E7) based on exceptional criteria but to bypassing multiple ranks within the Enlisted rank structure does not happen, though a field promotion from enlisted to commissioned officer is not unheard of in times of war.

Comment: In the case of him needing more rank to do his job, the military has more likely tendency to promote him to the rank of a junior officer which would outrank his previous position and responsibilities.

Comment: @Thaddeus Yes, an O1 outranks an E9.

Comment: @Morgan Thank you for the enlightenment. I am one step closer to knowing everything there is to know.

Comment: It could be that 'they' decided to advance him that far in rank to further give the sense of the story 'moving forward'. Or maybe they just felt that having a Major character (pun intended) with stripes from shoulder-to-elbow would look cooler. I haven't been able to find any (movie meta) commentaries about the subject thus far.

Comment: @Xantec I'm here for you bro.

Comment: I challenge the idea that he would need a promotion just to do his job. You need *clearance* to do a more highly-classified job, not pay grade. I once knew a Staff Sergeant working in a position that was billed for a Master.

Answer (score 4):

I fail to see the problem. Yes, he's certainly very young to have been promoted from [Technical Sergeant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_sergeant) in the first Transformer film to [Chief Master Sergeant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_master_sergeant) two and a bit years later but it's not without precedent in the USAF and he certainly wouldn't be the youngest by quite a wide margin.

There have been a considerable number of people promoted to that grade at a younger age, notably [Orville C. "Chuck" Miller](http://archive.thv11.com/news/article/38387/0/Kennedy-Honor-Guard-Member-Dies) who attained the rank at the age of 31 and [Desire L. "Dutch" D'Orange, Jr](http://www.legacy.com/obituaries/atlanta/obituary.aspx?n=desire-l-dorange-dutch&pid=19209657&fhid=4912). who attained the rank at the age of 29.

It's likely that with **the planet on a war footing**, with **his team involved in regular briefings with the President and Chiefs of Staff** and with **the opportunity to engage in high-level training**, any candidate would be very well placed to receive enhanced promotion prospects. On top of that his character is portrayed as being **the best of the best of the best** both physically and mentally.

As he says in this cast interview; He's at the top of the rankings **due to his close work with the autobots** and **because he's in control of coordinating what happens on the ground and what happens in the air**.

Comment: `the best of the best of the best` So you're saying he is a MiB agent too?

Comment: @Richard Great research as usual... but... He says in that interview that he's a Master Sergeant (E7) but wears the rank of a Chief Master Sergeant (E9) and says he's the highest (enlisted) rank and biggest dog in the AF. Both Command Chief Master Sergeant and Chief Master Sergeant of the Air Force hold higher enlisted rank/position.

Comment: Also, why is he now packin' such high enlisted rank while Lenox is still but a lowly Captain?

Comment: @Xantec - you may have +1 for spotting the reference.